# можно показать max элементы многомерного массива с помощью рекурсии?

Tags: javascript

let x = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, [8, 9], 10, 11], 12], 13, [14]];

Comment: и что это за код в вопросе?

Comment: вы определитесь, вам либо один максимальный найти надо,  или определите критерий, по какому признаку надо определять эти элементы, коли их несколько.

Comment: внимание, ответ - `Да, можно!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function maxDeep(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
        const res = Array.isArray(val) ? maxDeep(val) : val;
        return acc < res ? res : acc;
    }, -Infinity);
}
let x = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, [8, 9], 10, 11], 12], 13, [14]];
console.log(maxDeep(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно получить максимальное значение в вашем массиве:

```
var y = function(x,max=-Infinity){
    x.forEach(function(item){
        if (Array.isArray(item)){
            item = y(item,max);
        }
        if (item > max) {
            max = item;
        }
    })
    return max;
};
```

Comment: это - плохое решение. попробуйте его на `let x = [-1, -2];`

Comment: Хорошее замечание. Исправил `max=0` на `max=-Infinity`. Теперь лучше. Спасибо.